# Исправьте ошибку пожалуйста

Tags: массивы, c, циклы

Ввести массив целых чисел, количество элементов которого заранее не известно. Признаком конца ввода массива является ввод четырех чисел, дающих в среднем арифметическом 10. Вывести массив на экран

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void)
{
    int *a;//Массив
    int n=0, i=0, s4, j, x=0, sum=0;

    printf("vvedite razmernost' massiva: ");
    scanf_s("%i",&n);

    a = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("a[%i] = ",i);
        scanf_s("%i",&a[i]);
    }
{

for(i=0; ; i++) {

  a[i%4] = x;
  sum += x;
  if (i>=3) {
    for(s4=j=0; j<4; j++) s4 += a[j];
    if (s4==40) break;
  }
}

    printf("%d\n", a[j]);}
    free(a);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что значат строки

     for(i=0; ; i++) {
     a[i%4] = x;

И зачем массив ранее надо было вводить? Да и 

     printf("vvedite razmernost' massiva: ");

если длина массива заранее неизвестна?

Comment: хотела написать, что четыре подряд введенных числа дают в сумме 40.
а printf для того чтобы пользователь ввел массив, как иначе?

Answer (score 3):

Может так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int *arr;
    int narr = 0, sizeOfarry=0; // narr -- количество введённых, sizeOfarray -- сколько выделено.
    int i, sum = 0;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    sizeOfarry = 4;
    while (1) {
        if(narr == sizeOfarry) { // массив заполнен, добавляем ещё 4 числа
            arr = realloc(arr, (sizeOfarry + 4)*sizeof(int));
            sizeOfarry += 4;
        }
        printf("arr[%d]=", narr);
        scanf("%d", arr+narr);
        sum += arr[narr];
        if(narr>3) sum -= arr[narr-4]; // убираем самое старое если введено более 4 чисел. 
                                       // Так в sum будет сумма последних 4х
        if(narr > 2 && sum == 40) break;  // если введено 3 и более чисел,
                                          // начинаем проверку на признак окончания sum == 40
        narr++;
    }
    for(i=0; i <= narr; i++) {
        printf(" %6d", arr[i]);
        if(i%10 == 9) putchar('\n'); // после 10-ти чисел перевод строки.
    }
    if(i%10 != 9) putchar('\n'); // после перевода строки были ещё числа.
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: значение типа "void *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int *"
как исправить?

Comment: исправила, спасибо

Comment: можно вас попросить подробно описать действия некоторых строк?

Comment: Можно. Спрашивайте. А пока добавил несколько комментариев.

Comment: @himiko,  а вот такие конструкции

    arr = realloc(arr, (sizeOfarry + 4)*sizeof(int));
    sizeOfarry += 4;

можно записывать и в одну строку

    arr = realloc(arr, (sizeOfarry += 4) * sizeof(int));

Аналогично для `malloc`.

Comment: @avp а если чуть снизить уровень садизма? В Си и так непривычному человеку бывает нелегко.